# java - get activity status of a printer

Tags: java, printing, java-print

I have implemented a printing system in java. I need to get printer status, So I used `AttributeSet` in this way:

```
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
AttributeSet attributeSet = service.getAttributes();
for (Attribute a : attributeSet.toArray()) {
     System.out.println(a.getName() + ": " + attributeSet.get(a.getClass()).toString());
}
```

This returns me below output(even if the printer is off or pause):

```
printer-name: EPSON LQ-350 ESC/P2
color-supported: not-supported
printer-is-accepting-jobs: accepting-jobs
queued-job-count: 0
```

But, I need to printer status more specific, for example I need to know whether the printer is **off** or **pause**, or whether **paper** is ok or not. How can I get exact printer status?

Comment: is PrintService implementation based on CUPS ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS ?

Comment: Remember that this is an interface for a print _service_, not a physical printer.  The attributes available will depend completely on the operating system and driver implementation.  You are at the mercy of the specific driver for the printer for hardware-specific status information.

Comment: @JimGarrison Could you explain me further?

Comment: @hamed he means that depending on the OS and the delivered driver from the printer you are limited in options. If the printer supports the delivering of this status information then you are able to achive this. But if it doesn´t then you are not. Basicly the answer to you question is, depending on the printers driver and the os this is not possible.